# Why React native push notification always showing two times?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am trying to show some local notification in React-Native, using [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) package, but when I am triggering the notification its always showing two times. This is the first time I am trying out react-native, so I think there might be some issues with the configuration itself.

Here is the codes I have done to make this working:

1. Installed package and linked

   > - npm install --save react-native-push-notification
   > - npx react-native link react-native-push-notification
2. Updated `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

   > Added following code above `application` tag

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

> Added following code inside application tag

```
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
              android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                  android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                  android:resource="@color/white"/>
```

3. Created a file `react-native-app\android\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml` and added following code:

```
      <resources>
          <color name="white">#FFF</color>
      </resources>
```

4. Following file got updated automatically while running `react-native link` command:

   > android/app/src/main/java/com/churchutility/MainApplication.java

```
      import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
```

5. Updated `android/build.gradle`, added following inside `buildScript` `ext` section:

```
 buildscript {
     ext {
+        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
+        firebaseVersion = "+"
 ----
```

6. File `android/settings.gradle`  got updated automatically:

```
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
```

7. In react native I created a class as below, and created a instance from `App.js`

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

export default class ReminderService {
  constructor() {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function(token) {
        global.alert('TOKEN:', token);
      },
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        global.alert('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
        // notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
    this.showNotification('Local notification', 'Not scheduled');
  }

  showNotification = (title, message) => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      title: title,
      message: message,
    });
  };
}
```

As per the expectation notification is showing, but its always showing two times in simulator and device.
Please let me know whats wrong I am doing here, or is there a better way or package to do this in `react-native`.